# PHPExcel Exception: Formula Error: Unexpected ,

Tags: php, phpexcel

Apparently im getting this issue when PHPExcel is trying to parse the formula `'=_xlfn.LOGNORM.INV(1-$AB2,$AW$6,$AX$6)'`

Any ideas of why this is happening? if comma `,` isn't the function argument delimiter then what is?

EDIT

according to: http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Lognorm-Inv-Function.html

lognorm.inv is basically just an alias for loginv.. so i tried adding:

```
'LOGNORM.INV' => array('category' => PHPExcel_Calculation_Function::CATEGORY_STATISTICAL,
'functionCall' => 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Statistical::LOGINV',
'argumentCount' => '3'
```

to Calculations.php, however this seems to result in the same error. So any other routes of action?

Comment: Excel normally uses semicolons `;` as separators in functions. Have you tried that? Or another guess - have you tried using the arguments in quotes?

Comment: @Michal - ; or , as a separator is locale-sensitive... internally, a comma is used

Comment: @netbrain - Using the alias, you'd need the full _xlfn.LOGNORM.INV rather than just LOGNORM.INV and you'd also need to modify the definition of CALCULATION_REGEXP_FUNCTION to allow an _ character

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you, ill look into it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Looks good, added the missing functions, and now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more likely to be the fact that it's failing to recognise _xlfn.LOGNORM.INV as a valid function, but throwing a confusing exception.... the Docs folder has a list of all the recognised function names, and whether they are supported by PHPExcel... and =_xlfn.LOGNORM.INV is not listed there

Answer (score 0):

There's very little information in your question with which to give you an answer.

But, I tried a [Google search](http://goo.gl/83IPh), and found [this](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/255425). Maybe it can help you debug.